# how do i get the newest folder created in the given directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i'm trying to get the name of the newest folder created in a given directory.
**this code gives me "debug assertion failed"**
**help me resolve it**

```
     string processName()
        {
            FILETIME bestDate = { 0, 0 };
            FILETIME curDate;
            string name;
            CFileFind finder;

            finder.FindFile("D:\teams_output""*.blg");                                   
            while (finder.FindNextFile())
            {
                finder.GetCreationTime(&curDate);
                if (CompareFileTime(&curDate, &bestDate) > 0)
                {
                    bestDate = curDate;
                    name = finder.GetFileName().GetString();       /*debug assertion failed*/               }
            }
            return name;
        }
```

Comment: The debug assertion should come with a message which will probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: ASSERT(m_hContext != NULL); - >this assertion failed.

Comment: And where is that assertion?

Comment: In the source code of FindFiles().

Answer (score 0):

```
finder.FindFile("D:\teams_output""*.blg");
```

should be (I guess)

```
finder.FindFile("D:\\teams_output\\*.blg");
```

`\t` is the tab chanracter

Comment: presumably this would just cause no files to be found rather than a debug assertion?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes you are right. So clearly the posted code is not the same as the actual code. Until that is fixed I'm not going to speculate.